# DomHelper to create new collapsible Panel

Tags: dom, extjs, panel

I'm new to ExtJs and I'm trying to create a collapsible panel and would like to insert it into the Dom. I'm doing it as follows:

```
this.foo_holder = Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, [{id : 'testdiv'}]);

       var fooPanel = {
          xtype         : 'panel',
          height        : 100,
          title         : 'fooPanel',
          titleCollapse : true,
          collapsed     : true,
          collapsible   : true,
          html          : 'Blah Blah'
        };

        Ext.DomHelper.append(this.foo_holder, fooPanel);
```

However, it just shows up the html when the panel is inserted. I don't see any title bar or title or any collapsible functionality. 
When I create the same panel before the dom is rendered, it shows up properly. But I need to add/remove panels later on.

Can anyone help ?

Also, Any input on how to remove the component dynamically would be extremely useful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easyly workaround with something like this :

```
var d = Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, '<div>' );
Ext.ComponentMgr.create(fooPanel).render(d);
```

This may not be the cleanest but works. hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure about this being the cleanest way or not (I'm quite a new bie to Extjs and web dev in general) but this works for me :) Thanks